# is this the right way to use if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

is this the right way to use if statement ? 
or i can't use if statement inside this script ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#customerTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Customer/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": [{
                "sName": "CustomerId",
                "bVisible": false
            }, {
                "sName": "NamaPerusahaan",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href="/Customer/Details/' +
                        oObj.aData[0] + '">' + oObj.aData[1] + '</a>';
                }
            }, {
                "sName": "Alamat1"
            }, {
                "sName": "Telephone"
            },
            //below is the datetime
            {
                "sName": "NonActiveDate",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    if(oObj.aData[4] <= @DateTime.Now) {
                        return '<span style="color:green">' + oObj.aData[4] + ' </span>';
                    } else {
                        return '<span style="color:red">' + oObj.aData[4] + ' </span>';
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "sName": "Edit",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href="/Customer/Edit/' + oObj.aData[0] + '" class="btn mini blue"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Edit</a>';
                }
            }, {
                "sName": "Delete",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                    return '<a href="/Customer/Edit/' + oObj.aData[0] + '" class="btn mini red"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

with this code my TglNonAktif font color become all green,i think i have the problem with the if statement :D
need help from anyone .....

Comment: `style="red"` Do you mean `style="color:red"` ?

Comment: Without you clarifying what your statement should check, no one will guess for you. The one error I spot is that your second span have no CSS rule to use with `red`, so it won't do anything.

Comment: yes its color red,its just typo,i will correct it

Comment: What does `@DateTime.Now` resolve to? Why do you think you have a problem with the if-statement? What `oObj` is the function called with, might it be a problem with the data?

Comment: yip if you use razor @DateTime.Now maybe you need to converto to string? @DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")?

Comment: I think the if-statement might be one of your lesser concerns..

Comment: You are trying to inject a server-side date/time value into your script at page load time. Then comparing data date/times against that page-load date/time. Is this what you really intended? **1)** Injecting into Javascript (instead of a value into a page element) is bad because you get no script-caching and it is all inline (so the page is bloated). **2)** The date formats must match, so we need to know what format an `oObj.aData[4]` is?

Comment: ...(and **3)** does some of your data really exist in the future? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** "is this the right way to use if statement?"

**A:** No, not really :)

Having Razor injection into lengthy JavaScript means you cannot place your JavaScript into a separate file (so no bundling or caching).

Your question raises too many other questions, but if your aim is to inject a client-side variable from the server, you are better off injecting into a single "global" variable (global in JS is `window`) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.loadDate = @(DateTime.Now.ToString('appropriateformattinghere'));
</script>
```

that can be referenced from any javascript file as

```
if(oObj.aData[4] <= window.loadDate)
```

The code above assume a number will be generated (which a date hopefully will be).

The key here is "what is the format of `oObj.aData[4]`"? Is it a JavaScript `Date` object? Is it milliseconds since Stephen Hawkings was born? please be specific (and/or provide an example).